# Compensating for x-y tilt?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am attempting to 3D print an object, however, I have a tilt in my x and y-axes. I would like to raise my base structure up to compensate for the tilt. Does anyone have a formula that would compensate for the tile and allow me to add a gradient to slowly increase the base by an x-y gradient giving let us say an x-tilt of a degrees and a y tilt of b degrees?

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ both horizontal, or is $y$ vertical? (There are different conventions.)

Comment: If they're both horizontal, and both tilted, then you can rotate it so that only one is tilted.

Comment: Hi John, and welcome. Regarding you question, I notice two problems: first, if your 3D printer does not print correctly your object, you should perhaps call the technical support, show them your code and ask for their help. This community can help you only for questions regarding mathematics, not for question on how to implement a given mathematical model on particular machines. Second, if your problem is the mathematical model of your object, you should post a description of it, possibly written using Mathjax, in order for the member to see it.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri -- I think he's just asking how to physically orient the machine.

Comment: @mr_e_man. Yes, it could be: hovever, for me it is difficult to give him a formula allowing him to correct the physical orientation of his printer, without having a picture of the problem.

Comment: X and y are both horizontal Z is vertical the angles are relative to the Z axis. typical tilt angles are less than 0.1 degrees

Answer (score 1):

If the horizontal $x$-axis is tilted vertically by angle $\alpha$, and the width is $A$, then trigonometry says that the height difference between the ends is

$$\Delta z_x \approx A\tan\alpha \approx A\sin\alpha$$

Likewise, if the $y$-axis is tilted by angle $\beta$, and the length is $B$, then

$$\Delta z_y \approx B\tan\beta \approx B\sin\beta$$

These approximations are good for small angles.